# pivot_root device or resource busy

Tags: linux

The following commands on Ubuntu 64bit on VMWare:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /newroot
cd /newroot
mkdir old-root
pivot_root . old-root
```

produce an error that I do not understand:

```
pivot_root: device or resource busy
```

Any ideas what might be the reason for that?

Edit: strace result

```
`strace pivot_root . old-root 
execve("/usr/sbin/pivot_root", ["pivot_root", ".", "old-root"], [/* 67 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x77e000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2df4135000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=124467, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 124467, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2df4116000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\36b\0075\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2096496, ...}) = 0`
```

Comment: try installing `strace` and running `strace pivot_root . old-root`. then paste the 5 or so lines directly preceding the error.

Comment: Is calling pivot_root in newroot causing the issue?  ie, cd /; privot_root newroot newroot/old-root

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015688/pivot-root-device-or-resource-busy

Answer (score 3):

You should unmount the **/proc** file system first and then execute your original set of commands.

```
umount /proc
mount /dev/sda1 /newroot
cd /newroot
mkdir old-root
pivot_root . old-root
```

Comment: but I can't unmount the `/proc` as there are all the current running processes...

Comment: @Romulus did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: unfortunately not
I was looking at OverlayFS instead of using

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error on a ubuntu 16.04 host running a 18.04 namespace root, but only on a plain directory, not need to umount the /proc first. The solution is to bind mount the directory first. Posted to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015688/pivot-root-device-or-resource-busy?noredirect=1&lq=1).